# Python columns function

Tags: python, list, google-apps-script, multiple-columns, percentage

I would like a function which will create columns through the modalities of the columns of a database.
These created columns will calculate the percent of the modalities for each observation

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to load data as JSON/Array.

```
import pandas as pd
hold_data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\Users\abdulalim\Desktop\Test\Products.csv')
hold_data.to_json (r'C:\Users\abdulalim\Desktop\Test\New_Products.json')
```

output: `{"Product":{"0":"Desktop Computer","1":"Tablet","2":"Printer","3":"Laptop"},"Price":{"0":700,"1":250,"2":120,"3":1200}}`

if data get as Array:

```
def get_data(request):
    hold_data = request.data
    for key in hold_data:
        print(key[0])
        print(key[1])
```

if data get as Json:

```
def get_data(request):
    hold_data = request.data
    hold_data['data1']
    hold_data['data2']
```

After you get the data than do what ever you want

Comment: Thanks abdulalim . So I want to modify the table A to obtain table B. Its a csv for python pandas

Comment: @SAKHOBaidy update my post. hope you'll fine it useful. Don't forget to up vote.